# How can I resize the UIImage to specific size

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, image-resizing

In my app, I am taking picture with camera and displaying it in 320*320 `UIView`. But as the image resolution is more than that of `UIView` its kinda look squeezed. Is there any way I can resize that image?

Comment: @Andreas: That is completely different questions. And that one talks about content adjustment.I am more interested in preserving the all the context of the image so even if I do some operations on image like cropping or slicing I won't loose the content of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can resize the image while preserving its aspect ratio. The code below is from a category for `UIImage`:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image 
              scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{

    float heightToWidthRatio = image.size.height / image.size.width;
    float scaleFactor = 1;
    if(heightToWidthRatio > 0) {
        scaleFactor = newSize.height / image.size.height;
    } else {
        scaleFactor = newSize.width / image.size.width;
    }

    CGSize newSize2 = newSize;
    newSize2.width = image.size.width * scaleFactor;
    newSize2.height = image.size.height * scaleFactor;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize2);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize2.width,newSize2.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: if this is a category, then what's the need for the image parameter? might as well use `self` instead

Answer (score 0):

I do this, but first I enable the photo picker to editable so it is default 1:1 aspect, like so:

```
imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES; //I think this is what you're really looking for
```

then I resize the image using this method:

```
-(UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(480.0, 480.0);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: I was not looking for imagePickerEditing but its  sure something I did not known. Thanks for sharing..

Comment: Yea, I mean if you're using 1:1 ratio's it's not a bad option if it fits well with your UI. It let's the user scale and position with an interface they're use to.