# Capture screen based on UIImage size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiimage

I have problem with capture a custom view. I am trying to set captured image with size `UIImage` image data's size, but when I take the screenshot the image goes like this ! :

[image]

The image shrinks ! 
Here is the code :

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((self.photoImage.size), false, UIScreen.main.scale)

        self.captureView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

        self.photoToShare = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        print(self.photoToShare.size) //the size is right 

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.photo.image = self.photoToShare!
```

What is the problem ?!

I tired :
`self.captureView.drawHierarchy(in: self.captureView.bounds , afterScreenUpdates: true)`

still no success

**EDIT**

I tried this method, captured and then crop it but still no success

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.captureView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
            self.captureView.drawHierarchy(in: self.captureView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            let cropRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (self.photoImage.size.width) , height: (self.photoImage.size.height))
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
            image?.draw(in: cropRect)
            let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            self.photo.image = finalImage
```

But image will be distorted :

[image]

Comment: Try calling `[self.captureView setNeedsLayout]; [self.captureView layoutIfNeeded]` right before the `UIGraphicsBeginContextWithOptions`. Also, if that doesn't work, instead of setting the size to the `photoImage.size`, try using the `self.captureView.bounds`.

Comment: Thanks I did not work ! actually I need the photo data size .

Comment: Have you tried to scale the captured image like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318020/how-can-i-resize-the-uiimage-to-specific-size ?

Comment: @Ellen Yes but Actually I need to capture UIIView with exact UIimage's data size width and height

Comment: Just to be sure while showing image in ImageView are you using AspectFit ratio or scale to fill?

Comment: @Ellen Yes ,,,,

Comment: Did you have a chance to test my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to capture screenshot of imageview with aspectToFit content mode & having no constant width & height with below method

```
func captureShot() {
        let layer : CALayer = self.imageView!.layer
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((layer.frame.size), false, 1.0);
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    }
```

& returned screenshot has same image size (229*220) which is original size of image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks !  I'll try

Comment: Thank you so much it works fine ! but I add a crop function to save Image as the image.image size .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extension UIView {
    var screenCapture: UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, opaque, 0.0)
        drawViewHierarchyInRect(bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

To put this in a UImageView:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = someView.screenCapture
imageView.frame = someFrame
someSuperview.addSubview(imageView)
```

(Sorry about all the `some`s, but hopefully it's not confusing :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Mc.Lover, why does the size have to be “IMAGE DATA SIZE”? Also, are you testing this on device or simulator?